# Passing variables in a YAML file to shell script

Tags: shell, yaml

I have the following YAML file to store all the variables I use for the shell script. How do I pass one of the variable to the shell script? Please provide an example if possible.

```
  testme:
    Numberofservers: 3
    EC2InstanceType: m4.2xlarge
    DetailedMonitoring: 'true'
    TerminationProtection: 'true'
    DataEBSVolumeSize: 200
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this bash script https://gist.github.com/pkuczynski/8665367
to read your yaml and access the yaml property as bash variable